# Where the Dyntopo button is located in Blender 2.8?

Tags: sculpting, sculpt

I would like to know where the Dyntopo (dynamic topology) button for sculpt mode is located in Blender 2.8.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sculpt>Toggle Dynamic Topology

[image]

Comment: Thank you! Thank you very much.

Comment: @user1853 Where is it 2.91?

Answer (score 0):

[image: Dyntopo in Blender 2.8]
The Dyntopo checkbox is in the new Tool Tab at the top of the Properties Panel.

Comment: Thank you very much.